# Adding pages to Github Pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a website with a url like `mywebsite.github.io` . I want to create `mywebsite.github.io/robots.txt`.

I know that this can be done by setting up a new repository and adding gh-pages branch but how can I do this from my main repository?

Answer (score 1):

When you created your Github page, it made a new repo with the contents of it.

It will be called .github.io, where  is... your user name.

Add files there.

https://guides.github.com/features/pages/

Comment: No, I'm talking about the url xyz.github.io/robots.txt . I want to be able to do that, if I simple add files to the repo itll be posted to xyz.github.io/...../robots.txt